# how to code to button event from new class?

Tags: c#

I am create a simple code for learning c#. i create windows form and place button and label. i want to click button, open folder browse dialog box and select folder. after press ok , i want to show the folder path on the label.
this work i know that work in button click event.
but, i try to this code write in new class. and call to button click event.
c# .Net framework 4.6

**main form code**

```
        static Folderbrowse folderbrowse = new Folderbrowse();

        private void btn_SelectFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void lbl_SelectFolderPath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}




Form1 theform1 = new Form1();
static void Browsedialog()
{
    FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

    }
}
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Using this: `Form1 theform1 = new Form1();`, you're creating a new instance of your Form1. **This is not the `Form1` your're currently showing**, it's another instance. Setting any property of this **new** instance won't change anything in the existing one. You can pass the **existing** instance of `Form1` in the constructor of `Folderbrowse` or open it with  `Folderbrowse.ShowDialog(this);`. `this` is the instance of `Form1` that, when passed in this way, becomes the `Folderbrowse.Owner`. You can use the `Owner` instance inside `Folderbrowse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a helper-class and call a method that opens the folderBrowserDialog and returns the selected path:

```
using XY;
...
private HelperClass helper = new HelperClass();

private void btn_SelectFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl_SelectFolderPath.Text = helper.GetFolderPath();
}
```

And this would be your other class:

```
namespace XY
{
    public class HelperClass
    {
        public string GetFolderPath()
        {
            var openFolderDialog = new OpenFolderDialog();
            if(openFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return openFolderDialog.SelectedPath;
            }   
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

In this case you could also make the helper-class or the method static, because you dont refer to anything to the rest of your code.